# Structuring large javascript code using RequireJS

Tags: django, backbone.js, requirejs

Am very new to RequireJS here and trying to learn how to adopt to the structure. As of now, I've managed to create a structure as following

[image: ddd]

above image shows the structure of my code. Where by the folder "my" is supposed to contain all my modules, I plan to write inside each module its own models.js, views.js to be used later on by backbone.js

At this point I have couple questions as following

1. Can anyone by looking at the structure tell if its a good idea or if I should reconsider?

The second question is have is related to how I should manage conditionally loading my modules. Below is my config.js file

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "libs/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min",
        "libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min",
        "my/base/module",
        "my/vehicle/module"],

    function($, ui, bootstrap, base, vehicle) {
        //plugins have been loaded.
        base.initialize();
        vehicle.initialize();

});
```

am still not sure how to load module vehicle when am browsing or load module accounts when am browsing accounts. The backend is developed using django, I could create several config.js files for each module but am not sure if this is the correct approach or not.

Comment: I noticed the Django tag on this question. If you're looking to optimize your RequireJS modules whenever you run `./manage.py collectstatic`, take a look at django-require. https://github.com/etianen/django-require (Disclaimer: I wrote this Django app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I setup RequireJS with JQuery within Python Django framework.
In base top level baset_site.html I have the following require.js config code between "head" tags:

```
<script>
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: "{% static '' %}",
        paths: {
            jquery: './js/jslibs/jquery-1.9.1',
            jqm: './js/jslibs/jquery.mobile-1.4.0',
            ajax_redirect: './js/ajax_redirect',
            make_filt_sel: './app_namespace/js/make_filt_sel'
        },
        shim: {
            "jquery": {
                exports: '$',
            },
            "jqm": {
                deps: ['jquery'],
                exports: '$.mobile'
            },
            "make_filt_sel": {
                deps: ['jquery', 'jqm'],
                exports: 'make_filt_sel'
            }
        }
    });

</script>

{% block header_scripts %}{% endblock header_scripts %}
```

Here's my ajax_redirect.js

```
/*
    JQuery Ajax typically does not redirect in Django. Need middleware to
    setup "class AjaxRedirect(object):" to fix redirection.
    Reference:
        http://hunterford.me/how-to-handle-http-redirects-with-jquery-and-django/
*/

(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( ['jquery'], function () {
            factory();
        });
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory();
    }
}( this, document, function ( ) {

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){
        if (xhr.status == 278){
            window.location.href =
                xhr.getResponseHeader("Location")
                    .replace(/\?.*$/, "?next="+window.location.pathname);
        }
    });

}));
```

Then I typically setup "block header_scripts" in the inherited templates as follows:

```
{% block header_scripts %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <script>

        if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
            // AMD {# Configure requirejs.config in base_site.html #}
            require(["./app_namespace/js/module_namespace/js_module"]);
        } else {
            // No AMD
            $.ajax({
                async:false,
                type:'GET',
                url: "{% static "app_namespace/js/make_filt_sel.js" %}",
                data:null,
                dataType:'script'
            });

            $.ajax({
                async:false,
                type:'GET',
                url: "{% static "app_namespace/js/module_namespace/js_module.js" %}",
                data:null,
                dataType:'script'
            });
        }

    </script>

{% endblock header_scripts %}
```

Here's an example of setting up a js_module.js with dependencies:

```
(function ( root, doc, factory ) {
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define( ['jquery', 'jqm', 'ajax_redirect', 'make_filt_sel'], function () {
            factory();
        });
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory();
    }
}( this, document, function ( ) {
    // A bunch of code
    $.mobile.document.on( "pagebeforecreate", function(e){
        // a bunch of code
        // Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
        $(function(){
            // a bunch of code
        }); // end of $( document ).ready()
    }); // end of $(document).on( "pagebeforecreate",

})); // end of (function ( root, doc, factory )
```

Answer (score 1):

The essence of requireJS is modularization . IF you are loading any scripts , you should put path configs into the rquireJS config section. However if you are want conditional use /loading of files . Then you have to wrap your code around define module . somewhat like this

```
require.config({

paths:
{
    jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min',
    jqueryui: 'libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min',
    bootstrap: 'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
},
shim: {
  'underscore': {
    exports: '_'
  },    
  'bootstrap': {
    deps: ['jquery'],
    exports: 'jquery'
  }
}


});



require(['app/jquery.app','jquery.bootstrap'], function (AppRouter) {
var app_view = new AppRouter;
}
```

Your app/jquery.app should be your starting point of your application.

You have to write this into main.js file and call it like this

```
<script data-main="/Scripts/main" src="/Scripts/libs/require/require.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and your jquery.app which is your starting point should look like this

```
define(['jquery','my/base/module','my/vehicle/module']],
      //plugins have been loaded.
    base.initialize();
    vehicle.initialize();
 });
```

Note that in define module I havent defined anything to be loaded for jquery ui and bootstrap . The reason is since jquery ui loads of its own and it uses jquery syntax . And bootstrap file actually depends on jquery . So use the shim config to load bootstrap.min.js. Basically Your config and starting point should define the paths + starting point . So thats how make it .